# Android Studio Hedgehog Emulator not opening

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio was updated to Hedgehog and when I try to run an emulator I get following error and don't know how to solve this:

> INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.23.0 (build_id 11150993) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath ~/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86/ WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature. WARNING | Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering. I1212 10:47:28.048754 7661 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled. I1212 10:47:28.056958 7661 FrameBuffer.cpp:486] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (Google Inc.) I1212 10:47:28.056975 7661 FrameBuffer.cpp:487] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader) I1212 10:47:28.056977 7661 FrameBuffer.cpp:488] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1) I1212 10:47:28.056980 7661 FrameBuffer.cpp:489] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 I1212 10:47:28.056982 7661 FrameBuffer.cpp:490] Graphics Device Extensions N/A WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port INFO | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 7661 INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report library_mode swangle_indirect gpu mode swangle_indirect INFO | Using security allow list from: ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/emulator_access.json WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio *** INFO | The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: /run/user/1000/avd/running/7661/jwks/2473f51d-d8fd-4cde-bbeb-09ce6a48b1a9/active.jwk INFO | Scanning /run/user/1000/avd/running/7661/jwks/2473f51d-d8fd-4cde-bbeb-09ce6a48b1a9 for jwk keys. FATAL | Unable to start observing /run/user/1000/avd/running/7661/jwks/2473f51d-d8fd-4cde-bbeb-09ce6a48b1a9, jwks will not be updated. 0 were keysets loaded. [7668:7668:20231212,104728.103677:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.103788:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.103989:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104043:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104092:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104330:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104376:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104422:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104473:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104524:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104569:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104615:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7668:20231212,104728.104661:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found [7668:7669:20231212,104728.125994:ERROR directory_reader_posix.cc:42] opendir /tmp/android-t3tr4ktys/emu-crash-33.1.23.db/attachments/bcb43c16-5bdc-4eae-a69f-0cfa984a64d1: No such file or directory (2)